# API documentation for FTPopen(), FTPclose() et. al. on Tandem

Tags: c, ftp, sftp, tandem, hp-nonstop

I need to write a SFTP server in C for a HP NonStop (Tandem). There's an existing FTP server using functions such as `FTPopen()`, `FTPput()` and `FTPclose()`.

Where can I find documentation on these functions?

As usual with HP NonStop documentation, Google is of little use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the HP NonStop TCP/IP Applications and Utilities User Guide

Chapter 8 is titled "FTP API External Specification". Information about the regular FTP server API is in there.

Note: 
If you have a recent version of Guardian on Itanium or Blade servers then it will either already come with HP NonStop SSH or you can buy it from HP extremely cheaply. This includes an SFTP server as part of the SSH implementation, which works for Guardian and OSS. It can be implemented without any downtime.

If you are on an S-Series server then that option from HP isn't available, but the same software is available commercially.